# SqlLite: Can we select rows as columns?

Tags: java, sqlite, pivot

Just needed a quick help if anyone can provide. I have a column `Product_name` with unique values in a table named `Products`.

What I want to do is `SELECT` each row of this table as a column and then for each row of this resulted query, if their exists a record with that specific transaction_id in a table named `Transactiondetails` which contains the foreign key from the table `Transactions`, pull up the quanity.

Table `transactiondetails` is designed to make the structure of the database in 3rd normal form. For example for a specific transaction id, the number of products and their quantities are all in seperate rows in the table `transactiondetails` with that specific transaction id.

Now, For example, if I have two products named `product A` and `product B` (that means two rows in the table `products`), then the resulted query should show like this

```
transaction_id | product A | product B
             1 |         5 |        10
```

I hope I made it understandable enough.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: SQLite does not have pivot functions; this is not possible.

Comment: I believe you could be able to implement very limited (fixed number of known products) functionality as cross-tab using `CASE...END` construct.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, names "rows" and "columns" do not refer to visual presentation (think "records" and "attributes"), so it is not possible, at least not in SQLite.

If you want to display data in "columns", then you have to do it in presentation layer, not in data layer. You'll have then vertical "rows" ("records") and horizontal "columns" ("attributes").

Comment: Does't `relational model` deals specifically with rows and columns? Or have I misunderstood your statement?

Comment: Yes, it does. I mean, rows are not defined as "stuff that goes horizontal" but rather "entities that have attributes", same for columns.

Comment: Then I would prefer `records` and `fields` analogy, since columns and rows are not equal entities in terms of indexing, keys, and such.

Comment: That's what I was trying to say:) English is not my first language.